# end two jquery animations simultaneously

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have two jquery animations running in two different elements. Both are triggered at the same time. Now i want to end these to animations at the same time irrespective of the durations each take to animate.

```
jQuery("#maindiv").animate({ scrollLeft:10 }, 500);
jQuery(".sidediv").animate({ marginLeft:-100 }, 500);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense, "irrespective of the durations"...the duration is by definition *how long it takes*.  Perhaps you have an example that clears this up?

Comment: @Nick, I imagine that the implication is he wants to synchronise the two animations; when one is 50% complete the other should **also** be 50% complete. Perhaps asking if there's a way to **1:** assess the progress of the animations relative to each other, and **2:** slow/increase the speed of an animation to maintain synchronicity. But I'm really not sure.

Comment: @David - Why not just have the same duration then?  It's the "irrespective of the durations" that really throws me.

Comment: @Nick, I have no idea. As you say, the question doesn't really make sense, it's just that I think the question he *asked* wasn't the question(s) he *meant* to ask.

Comment: @David, Yes you got me right. The animations starts at the same time but due to the duration they take to animate, one finished after the other. But i want then to finish together so the animation looks smooth and single. Hope this is possible. Thanks...

Comment: Unfortunately, as jQuery doesn't appear to have a concept of 'key-frames,' I don't think that it is. Your best bet would be to adjust the durations manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to **forcibly** end them, use the [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method.

```
jQuery('#maindiv, .sidediv').stop();
```